# List View not updated

Tags: android, listview, broadcast, intentservice

I am having a list view in activity.
In Activity I have set alarm at particular interval  to start intent service to get data from server,after it finishes a server call response is broadcasted back to activity from intent service and update the list view with new data..Everything works fine..
But when I leave that activity and again come back to same activity with list view,my intent service is broadcasting data but list view is not updated with data,gives me blank list view.. 
How to get list view inflated with data when again navigation to that activity..
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 uradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood properly, you should just call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in your adapter.